# Позиционирование дочернего элемента с одинаковым классом

Tags: html, css

Есть таблица, в которой в одном из "td" вставлена кнопка "Редактировать" с определённым классом, за ней сразу же идёт "form" в котором после нескольких "input"-ов идёт кнопка "Удалить" с таким же классом как и кнопка "Редактировать". Проблема в том, что эти две кнопки смещены друг к другу, а хотелось бы сместить их к правому краю и сделать отступ друг от дружки. Для подробного описания я привёл код ниже.

```css
html,
body,
div,
span,
object,
iframe,
h1,
h2,
h3,
h4,
h5,
h6,
p,
blockquote,
pre,
a,
abbr,
address,
cite,
code,
del,
dfn,
em,
img,
ins,
q,
small,
strong,
sub,
sup,
dl,
dt,
dd,
ol,
ul,
li,
fieldset,
form,
label,
legend,
input,
table,
caption,
tbody,
tfoot,
thead,
tr,
th,
td,
figure {
  border: 0;
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
}
info th {
  width: 30%;
}
table th {
  background: #E9E6E0;
  border: 1px solid #ccc;
  padding: 13px;
  text-align: left;
  font-size: 13px;
  font-weight: 600;
  vertical-align: top;
}
table td {
  background: #fff;
  border: 1px solid #ccc;
  color: #454545;
  padding: 13px;
}
.b-info .gradient-button {
  float: right;
}
button,
input,
select,
textarea {
  margin: 0;
  vertical-align: baseline;
  outline: none;
  -webkit-box-shadow: none;
  -moz-box-shadow: none;
  box-shadow: none;
  -webkit-transition: all 0.2s ease-in;
  -moz-transition: all 0.2s ease-in;
  -o-transition: all 0.2s ease-in;
  -ms-transition: all 0.2s ease-in;
  transition: all 0.2s ease-in;
}
button,
input,
select,
textarea {
  margin: 0;
  vertical-align: baseline;
  outline: none;
 -webkit-box-shadow: none;
  -moz-box-shadow: none;
  box-shadow: none;
  -webkit-transition: all 0.2s ease-in;
  -moz-transition: all 0.2s ease-in;
  -o-transition: all 0.2s ease-in;
  -ms-transition: all 0.2s ease-in;
  transition: all 0.2s ease-in;
}

.gradient-button, .wpcf7-submit, .form-submit #submit, button, input[type="button"], input[type="reset"], input[type="submit"] {
    font-size: 13px;
    line-height: 28px;
    font-weight: 700;
    color: #F74B60!important;
    height: 32px;
    padding: 0 5px !important;
    text-align: center;
    display: inline-block;
    background-color: #fff;
    border-radius: 6px;
    border: 2px solid #F74B60;
}

table {
    border-collapse: collapse;
    border-spacing: 0;
    width: 100%;
    margin: 0 0 30px;
}
a {
    color: #384250;
    font-weight: 600;
    text-decoration: none;
    -webkit-transition: all 0.1s ease-in 0.1s;
    -moz-transition: all 0.1s ease-in 0.1s;
    -o-transition: all 0.1s ease-in 0.1s;
    -ms-transition: all 0.1s ease-in 0.1s;
    transition: all 0.1s ease-in 0.1s;
}
info th {
    width: 30%;
}
table th {
    background: #E9E6E0;
    border: 1px solid #ccc;
    padding: 13px;
    text-align: left;
    font-size: 13px;
    font-weight: 600;
    vertical-align: top;
}
input, button, select, textarea {
    font-family: inherit;
    font-size: inherit;
    line-height: inherit;
}
```

```html
<table>
  <tbody>
    <tr>
      <th>Vacancy Id:</th>
      <td>
        32 <a href="https://sunnygeorgia.travel/create-vacancies/?fesid=32" class="gradient-button" title="Редактировать">Редактировать</a> 
        <form method="post" name="delete_vacancy_32" id="delete_vacancy_32">
          <input type="hidden" class="delete_vacancy_id" value="32">
          <input type="hidden" id="_wpnonce" name="_wpnonce" value="dec425659d">
          <input type="hidden" name="_wp_http_referer" value="/my-vacancies/?accid=6035"> <a href="#" class="gradient-button button-delete button-delete-vacancy" title="Удалить">Удалить</a> 
        </form>
      </td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <th>Тип номера:</th>
      <td>Улучшенный двухместный номер</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <th>Свободные номера:</th>
      <td>10</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <th>Дата начала:</th>
      <td>24.08.2016</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <th>Дата окончания:</th>
      <td>31.08.2017</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <th>Цена:</th>
      <td>$25.00</td>
    </tr>
  </tbody>
</table>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```css
html,
body,
div,
span,
object,
iframe,
h1,
h2,
h3,
h4,
h5,
h6,
p,
blockquote,
pre,
a,
abbr,
address,
cite,
code,
del,
dfn,
em,
img,
ins,
q,
small,
strong,
sub,
sup,
dl,
dt,
dd,
ol,
ul,
li,
fieldset,
form,
label,
legend,
input,
table,
caption,
tbody,
tfoot,
thead,
tr,
th,
td,
figure {
  border: 0;
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
}
info th {
  width: 30%;
}
table th {
  background: #E9E6E0;
  border: 1px solid #ccc;
  padding: 13px;
  text-align: left;
  font-size: 13px;
  font-weight: 600;
  vertical-align: top;
}
table td {
  background: #fff;
  border: 1px solid #ccc;
  color: #454545;
  padding: 13px;
}
.b-info .gradient-button {
  float: right;
}
button,
input,
select,
textarea {
  margin: 0;
  vertical-align: baseline;
  outline: none;
  -webkit-box-shadow: none;
  -moz-box-shadow: none;
  box-shadow: none;
  -webkit-transition: all 0.2s ease-in;
  -moz-transition: all 0.2s ease-in;
  -o-transition: all 0.2s ease-in;
  -ms-transition: all 0.2s ease-in;
  transition: all 0.2s ease-in;
}
button,
input,
select,
textarea {
  margin: 0;
  vertical-align: baseline;
  outline: none;
 -webkit-box-shadow: none;
  -moz-box-shadow: none;
  box-shadow: none;
  -webkit-transition: all 0.2s ease-in;
  -moz-transition: all 0.2s ease-in;
  -o-transition: all 0.2s ease-in;
  -ms-transition: all 0.2s ease-in;
  transition: all 0.2s ease-in;
}

.gradient-button, .wpcf7-submit, .form-submit #submit, button, input[type="button"], input[type="reset"], input[type="submit"] {
    font-size: 13px;
    line-height: 28px;
    font-weight: 700;
    color: #F74B60!important;
    height: 32px;
    padding: 0 5px !important;
    text-align: center;
    display: inline-block;
    background-color: #fff;
    border-radius: 6px;
    border: 2px solid #F74B60;
}

table {
    border-collapse: collapse;
    border-spacing: 0;
    width: 100%;
    margin: 0 0 30px;
}
a {
    color: #384250;
    font-weight: 600;
    text-decoration: none;
    -webkit-transition: all 0.1s ease-in 0.1s;
    -moz-transition: all 0.1s ease-in 0.1s;
    -o-transition: all 0.1s ease-in 0.1s;
    -ms-transition: all 0.1s ease-in 0.1s;
    transition: all 0.1s ease-in 0.1s;
}
info th {
    width: 30%;
}
table th {
    background: #E9E6E0;
    border: 1px solid #ccc;
    padding: 13px;
    text-align: left;
    font-size: 13px;
    font-weight: 600;
    vertical-align: top;
}
input, button, select, textarea {
    font-family: inherit;
    font-size: inherit;
    line-height: inherit;
}

td > .gradient-button {
float: right;
margin-left: 10px;
}

td > form {
float:right
}
```

```html
<table>
  <tbody>
    <tr>
      <th>Vacancy Id:</th>
      <td>
        32 <a href="https://sunnygeorgia.travel/create-vacancies/?fesid=32" class="gradient-button" title="Редактировать">Редактировать</a> 
        <form method="post" name="delete_vacancy_32" id="delete_vacancy_32">
          <input type="hidden" class="delete_vacancy_id" value="32">
          <input type="hidden" id="_wpnonce" name="_wpnonce" value="dec425659d">
          <input type="hidden" name="_wp_http_referer" value="/my-vacancies/?accid=6035"> <a href="#" class="gradient-button button-delete button-delete-vacancy" title="Удалить">Удалить</a> 
        </form>
      </td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <th>Тип номера:</th>
      <td>Улучшенный двухместный номер</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <th>Свободные номера:</th>
      <td>10</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <th>Дата начала:</th>
      <td>24.08.2016</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <th>Дата окончания:</th>
      <td>31.08.2017</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <th>Цена:</th>
      <td>$25.00</td>
    </tr>
  </tbody>
</table>
```

0
голос против

Все можно сделать )
Будет работать независимо от id формы

Answer (score 0):

Первая версия, которая пришла мне в голову - просто для каждой кнопки(для тайтла) задать свой айдишник. 
Так же можно сделать что-то на подобии этого:

`a {
 float: right;
  margin-bottom:25px;
    color: #384250;
    font-weight: 600;
    text-decoration: none;
    -webkit-transition: all 0.1s ease-in 0.1s;
    -moz-transition: all 0.1s ease-in 0.1s;
    -o-transition: all 0.1s ease-in 0.1s;
    -ms-transition: all 0.1s ease-in 0.1s;
    transition: all 0.1s ease-in 0.1s;
}`

Но опять же, у вас не получится изменять их положение относительно друг друга, так как стиль приписывается определённому тайтлу. 
Надеюсь я вам помог.

С Уважением Антон

Answer (score 0):

```css
html,
body,
div,
span,
object,
iframe,
h1,
h2,
h3,
h4,
h5,
h6,
p,
blockquote,
pre,
a,
abbr,
address,
cite,
code,
del,
dfn,
em,
img,
ins,
q,
small,
strong,
sub,
sup,
dl,
dt,
dd,
ol,
ul,
li,
fieldset,
form,
label,
legend,
input,
table,
caption,
tbody,
tfoot,
thead,
tr,
th,
td,
figure {
  border: 0;
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
}
info th {
  width: 30%;
}
table th {
  background: #E9E6E0;
  border: 1px solid #ccc;
  padding: 13px;
  text-align: left;
  font-size: 13px;
  font-weight: 600;
  vertical-align: top;
}
table td {
  background: #fff;
  border: 1px solid #ccc;
  color: #454545;
  padding: 13px;
}
.b-info .gradient-button {
  float: right;
}
button,
input,
select,
textarea {
  margin: 0;
  vertical-align: baseline;
  outline: none;
  -webkit-box-shadow: none;
  -moz-box-shadow: none;
  box-shadow: none;
  -webkit-transition: all 0.2s ease-in;
  -moz-transition: all 0.2s ease-in;
  -o-transition: all 0.2s ease-in;
  -ms-transition: all 0.2s ease-in;
  transition: all 0.2s ease-in;
}
button,
input,
select,
textarea {
  margin: 0;
  vertical-align: baseline;
  outline: none;
 -webkit-box-shadow: none;
  -moz-box-shadow: none;
  box-shadow: none;
  -webkit-transition: all 0.2s ease-in;
  -moz-transition: all 0.2s ease-in;
  -o-transition: all 0.2s ease-in;
  -ms-transition: all 0.2s ease-in;
  transition: all 0.2s ease-in;
}

.gradient-button, .wpcf7-submit, .form-submit #submit, button, input[type="button"], input[type="reset"], input[type="submit"] {
    font-size: 13px;
    line-height: 28px;
    font-weight: 700;
    color: #F74B60!important;
    height: 32px;
    padding: 0 5px !important;
    text-align: center;
    display: inline-block;
    background-color: #fff;
    border-radius: 6px;
    border: 2px solid #F74B60;
}

table {
    border-collapse: collapse;
    border-spacing: 0;
    width: 100%;
    margin: 0 0 30px;
}
a {
    color: #384250;
    font-weight: 600;
    text-decoration: none;
    -webkit-transition: all 0.1s ease-in 0.1s;
    -moz-transition: all 0.1s ease-in 0.1s;
    -o-transition: all 0.1s ease-in 0.1s;
    -ms-transition: all 0.1s ease-in 0.1s;
    transition: all 0.1s ease-in 0.1s;
}
info th {
    width: 30%;
}
table th {
    background: #E9E6E0;
    border: 1px solid #ccc;
    padding: 13px;
    text-align: left;
    font-size: 13px;
    font-weight: 600;
    vertical-align: top;
}
input, button, select, textarea {
    font-family: inherit;
    font-size: inherit;
    line-height: inherit;
}

#delete_vacancy_32, .gradient-button {float: right; margin-left: 10px;}
```

```html
<table>
  <tbody>
    <tr>
      <th>Vacancy Id:</th>
      <td>
        32 
        <form method="post" name="delete_vacancy_32" id="delete_vacancy_32">
          <input type="hidden" class="delete_vacancy_id" value="32">
          <input type="hidden" id="_wpnonce" name="_wpnonce" value="dec425659d">
          <input type="hidden" name="_wp_http_referer" value="/my-vacancies/?accid=6035"> <a href="#" class="gradient-button button-delete button-delete-vacancy" title="Удалить">Удалить</a> 
        </form>
  <a href="https://sunnygeorgia.travel/create-vacancies/?fesid=32" class="gradient-button" title="Редактировать">Редактировать</a>
      </td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <th>Тип номера:</th>
      <td>Улучшенный двухместный номер</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <th>Свободные номера:</th>
      <td>10</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <th>Дата начала:</th>
      <td>24.08.2016</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <th>Дата окончания:</th>
      <td>31.08.2017</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <th>Цена:</th>
      <td>$25.00</td>
    </tr>
  </tbody>
</table>
```

Comment: Дело в том, что это подойдёт только для этого ID (32), а для других это ведь не будет применяться.

Comment: @ВалерийЕмельянов замените `#delete_vacancy_32` на `form`. А лучше всем этим формам добавить общий класс и прописать его вместо `form`.